# Trim a string with AWK

Tags: awk

Original format of the file (space separated):

```
a b http://c.com/?longlongname e f g
```

I want to trim the 3rd field (`http://c.com/?longlongname`) into `c.com`, and
keep the rest fields as the same. I would like to use `awk` to do this task.
Could anyone give me any hint?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{split($3, z, "/"); $3=z[3]} 1'
```

- take third field
- split on `/`
- change value of third field to third result of split
- print line

Result

```
a b c.com e f g
```